# processing stdin data blocs with python and groupby

Tags: python, group-by, python-itertools

The objective is to have a python script process sorted `stdin` line by line, collect 'data blocs' having the same key, and then output that bloc as JSON (or any other single object) once the key changes. At this stage I just want to be able to isolate key & data blocs by using `groupby` and `itertools` correctly. In the example below, there are two blocs of three rows each. The setup is

```
 cat data.csv | python qwe.py
```

where `data.csv` is

```
 1,this,is
 1,a,test
 1,hope,it
 2,works,well
 2,and,I
 2,move,forward
```

and `qwe.py` is

```
 import itertools
 import operator
 import sys
 import re

 def main(argv):
  for key, bloc in itertools.groupby( sys.stdin.readline().split(',') ,
                                 key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
      print '-----' + key
      print list(bloc)

 if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv)
```

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.stdin.readline()` yield only first line `1,this,is\n`. You should iterate all lines.

Instead of split each line manually, use [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

```
import csv
import itertools
import operator
import sys

def main():
    reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
    for key, bloc in itertools.groupby(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
        print '-----' + key
        print list(bloc)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    main()
```

Comment: That's it, thanks. Time i've spent...I know the module, but I didn't think of applying it to sys.stdin.